# Using jQuery functions on some websites cause Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-console

I'm learning jQuery by writing some code in Chrome's console, e.g. adding an `id` to a DOM element and then executing jQuery functions.

On some websites (for example [Google](https://www.google.com)) I get `Uncaught TypeError` and on others, I don't. Here is an example:

DOM modification:

```
<input id="test" aria-label="Szukaj w Google" name="btnK" type="submit" jsaction="sf.chk">
```

Console:

```
$("#test").hide()
```

Error:

```
VM598:1 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hide is not a function
at <anonymous>:1:12
```

The same flow on other websites (for example [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)) works. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is not loaded on many websites on the internet. That's why you get your error message `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hide is not a function`, because actually the `$` is not jQuery, rather another function, object, or it's just simply undefined.

Although you can find [**one of many versions of jQuery**](https://code.jquery.com/jquery/) loaded on numerous websites, several companies/projects/websites don't use jQuery, or they use a [**custom build of it**](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-build-your-own-custom-jquery--net-27113), or something else under the `$` sign, or just not at all.

---

On a website, **by default**:

- the `$` sign is an alias for [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- the double `$$` sign is an alias for [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

If that particular website doesn't override those variables with another implementation (e.g. custom function, library, jQuery, etc.). [**More on this**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselector)

*Credit to [@AuxTaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9029328/auxtaco)*

---

If you need to have jQuery on a website (e.g. **for development purposes**), where it's not present, [**you can inject it into the website**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573076/how-to-inject-jquery-to-any-webpage).

Comment: But when I execute for example $("#test").value = "newValue" it works on google and I can change string on search button, so I assume that jQuery is loaded on google

Comment: Probably they have a custom library under the `$`, or it's a custom-built jQuery. If you use Chrome, you can check it out under the Network and Sources tabs, what code do they really use under the `$` sign.

Comment: @SigGP It's very common to use `$` as a short name for a function that looks up elements. But it's not always jQuery.

Comment: When `$` is not otherwise defined, [it's an alias for `document.querySelector`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#queryselector) in the console.