# Use JQuery in an inject.js file executed under background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension where my ***background.js*** script file will execute ***inject.js*** script file on a certain event.

I also have a local ***jquery.min.js*** file which I have included in my ***manifest.json*** file so that I can use it in my ***background.js*** file.

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery.min.js","background.js"]
  },
```

However, I am not sure how can use jquery in my ***inject.js*** file. I tried using `/// <reference path="jquery.min.js" />` but that didn't work.

Any thoughts on how can I use jquery and other js libraries in my ***inject.js***?

Below if my *background.js* code

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    //To verify if jQuery is working  
    if (jQuery) {
        console.log("Jquery on");
    } else {
        console.log("Jquery off");
    }

    if(activeTabs.length===0){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:"js/inject.js"});
    }
}
```

Comment: Inject `jquery.min.js` before injecting `inject.js`.

Comment: How are you using / including / executing `inject.js`? Without this information the question can't be answered

Comment: @Xan I added the background.js code.

Comment: Have you tried to check this [SO post (How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)? And this another [SO post (How to inject jquery to any webpage)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26573076/how-to-inject-jquery-to-any-webpage)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to inject `jquery.min.js` before injecting `inject.js`. In your case:

```
if(activeTabs.length===0){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:'jquery.min.js'},function(){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file:'js/inject.js'});
    });
}
```